# Why does empty logical vector pass the stopifnot() check?

Tags: r, error-handling, boolean, is-empty

Today I found that some of my `stopifnot()` tests are failing because the passed arguments evaluate to empty logical vectors.

Here is an example:

```
stopifnot(iris$nosuchcolumn == 2)  # passes without error
```

This is very unintuitive and seems to contradict a few other behaviours. Consider:

```
isTRUE(logical())
> FALSE

stopifnot(logical())
# passes
```

So `stopifnot()` passes even when this argument is not `TRUE`.
But furthermore, the behaviour of the above is different with different types of empty vectors.

```
isTRUE(numeric())
> FALSE

stopifnot(numeric())
# Error: numeric() are not all TRUE
```

Is there some logic to the above, or should this be considered a bug?

Comment: in `stopifnot`, there is a check for is.logical

Comment: This is just a small list among some inconsistencies in R, unfortunately. I don't mean that to be harsh against R so much as admitting that R is far from perfect in behavior-consistency. I agree that this seems counterintuitive. In these examples, one might consider including `length(...) > 0` (or `NROW(iris) > 0`, given the first conditionals work on a frame).

Comment: [stopifnot with logical(0)](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2015-December/434610.html)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, especially @Henrik, I think that thread really answers the question about the logic behind this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers cover the practical reasons why `stopifnot` behaves the way it does; but I agree with Karolis that [the thread linked by Henrik](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2015-December/434610.html) adds the real explanation of why this is the case:

> As author stopifnot(), I do agree with [OP]'s  "gut feeling" [...] that
> `stopifnot(dim(x) == c(3,4))` [...][should] stop in the case
> where x is a simple vector instead of a matrix/data.frame/... with
> dimensions `c(3,4)` ... but [...] the gut feeling is wrong because of the fundamental lemma of logic: [...]
>
> **"All statements about elements of the empty set are true"**
>
> Martin Maechler, ETH Zurich

> Also, [...], any() is to "|" what sum() is to "+" and what all() is to
> "&" and prod() is to "*". All the operators have an identity element,
> namely FALSE, 0, TRUE, and 1 respectively, and the generic convention
> is that for an empty vector, we return the identity element, for the
> reason given above.
>
> Peter D.

Answer (score 4):

The comments by akrun and r2evans are spot on.

However, to give details on why specifically this happens and why you're confused vs. `isTRUE()` behavior, note that `stopifnot()` checks for three things; the check is (where `r` is the result of the expression you pass):

```
if (!(is.logical(r) && !anyNA(r) && all(r)))
```

So, let's take a look:

```
is.logical(logical())
# [1] TRUE
!anyNA(logical())
# [1] TRUE
all(logical())
# [1] TRUE

is.logical(numeric())
# [1] FALSE
!anyNA(numeric())
# [1] TRUE
all(numeric())
# [1] TRUE
```

So, the only reason why `logical()` passes while `numeric()` fails is because `numeric()` is not "logical," as suggested by akrun. For this reason, you should avoid checks that may result in logical vectors of length 0, as suggested by r2evans.

Comment: Thanks. I see the line with `is.logical()`, and now get why it behaves this way, but it still seems like a bug. A simple addition of `&& length(r) > 0` would probably fix it...

Comment: @KarolisKoncevičius In my opinion it would be fair to call it a bug, though I think where the line between "bug" and function not behaving as *you* expect can be fuzzy sometimes, and people draw that line in different places. You may want to check out https://www.r-project.org/bugs.html to see where the R Project stands on what counts as a bug and whether it's worth your time to submit a bug report.

Comment: the r-help thread in the comment by Henrik really answered the question about why it behaves that way. Maybe you can include that link in your answer too, and then I would accept it. Just because comments are prone to being deleted...